# MongoDb atlas: { status: 400, message: "Bad Request" } This is a bad request. Please try again later

Tags: mongodb, mern, mongodb-atlas

I have started following a tutorial to create a social network by using the MERN stack. In the beginning, I have to set-up the mongoDb configuration. 
The first thing, I had to do is create an account on [MongoDB Cloud](https://cloud.mongodb.com). However, strangely enough this wasn't even possible. After, I enter my information and click on create account, I get this error:

> { status: 400,   message: "Bad Request" }

[image]

I have emailed them on : atlas-help@mongodb.com . And I am still waiting for a response.
Any idea what might be causing this error?

Comment: Also you can try to inform about your issue on their [new mongodb forum](https://community.mongodb.com).

Answer (score 0):

I just face the same problem. I do not know why this is happening but a workaround is to click Sing in at the bottom and then log in with a google account.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue had to do with the originating IP address.

I had the same problem. My solution was to disconnect from my VPN, and attempt to sign up again.

It worked fine. Note that, after sign up, you can switch on your VPN again. Thankfully!